# How do I pass values through variables to a macro in sas

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Here is my code

```
%macro redemptions1(startdate, enddate, sd, ed, sunday1, sunday2);
data _null_;
%put &startdate;
run;

%mend redemptions1;
data _null_;
format tday date9.;
format sd date9.;
format ed date9.;
tday=today();
if weekday(tday) = 1 then do; ed = intnx('day',tday,-9); sd = intnx('day',tday,-15);end;
if weekday(tday) = 2 then do; ed = intnx('day',tday,-3); sd = intnx('day',tday,-9);end;
if weekday(tday) = 3 then do; ed = intnx('day',tday,-4); sd = intnx('day',tday,-10);end;
if weekday(tday) = 4 then do; ed = intnx('day',tday,-5); sd = intnx('day',tday,-11);end;
if weekday(tday) = 5 then do; ed = intnx('day',tday,-6); sd = intnx('day',tday,-12);end;
if weekday(tday) = 6 then do; ed = intnx('day',tday,-7); sd = intnx('day',tday,-13);end;
if weekday(tday) = 7 then do; ed = intnx('day',tday,-8); sd = intnx('day',tday,-14);end;
startdate = (year(sd) - 1900) * 10000 + month(sd) * 100 + day(sd);
enddate = (year(ed) - 1900) * 10000 + month(ed) * 100 + day(ed);
sunday1 = year(intnx('day',sd,-6))*10000+month(intnx('day',sd,-6))*100+day(intnx('day',sd,-6));
sunday2 = year(intnx('day',sd,1))*10000+month(intnx('day',sd,1))*100+day(intnx('day',sd,1));
%redemptions1(startdate,enddate,sd,ed,sunday1,sunday2); 
run;
```

If i pass values through the variables startdate,enddate etc, The redemeptions1 macro just prints 'startdate' instead of actually printing the value of startdate. How do I get it to print the value contained in the variable(s)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct a call to the macro as a text string and then tell SAS to execute it using either `CALL EXECUTE` or the `DOSUBL` function.

The parameters on a macro call need to be literal text giving the values you want. Your call in the data step starts `%redemptions1(startdate,...` so the first parameter is the literal text `startdate` and that's what the macro prints. Instead, you could do something like:

```
myCall = '%redemptions1(' || startdate || ')';
call execute(myCall);
```

This construct the necessary call - something like `%redemptions1(09MAR2017)` - and then executes it. You could of course do this in one line:

```
call execute('%redemptions1(' || startdate || ')');
```

You'll need to fill in the values of the other parameters, of course.

Your date calculations look a bit sketchy, by the way - `startdate` and `enddate` may not contain the values you think they do. Please look up the `dhms` function to see if that might help. You're creating a number like '1170309' for today's date - 1 million, 170 thousand, 3 hundred and 9. The year value is very odd - do you really want 117 (2017 - 1900)?. If you ask SAS to handle that value as a date, it will treat it as a number of days since 01JAN1960, which would be some date way in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your response Chris. I did try the above mentioned approach and it says variable not initialized. I tried to PUT startdate in the macro, by a call through execute, but it threw me the error "variable is uninitialized". W.r.t the date, yes I am looking for that specific format because my dataset demands it.

Comment: What says 'variable not initialized'? Make sure the CALL EXECUTE is part of the data step, ie before the final 'run;'. In the macro, you can remove the 'data _null_;' and 'run;' lines and just keep the '%put' statement, but I wouldn't expect any other messages. Try the two-line version of the CALL EXECUTE and add a 'put myCall=;' line to confirm what is being executed. Setting OPTIONS MPRINT SYMBOLGEN may also help to diagnose the problem.